# Put json array inside json object in PHP

Tags: php, json

Hello Stackoverflow community, i'm little bit confused how i can achieve this. So this is how my json response should look:

```
some_array: [
    {
        some_json_object_atribute_1:
        some_json_object_atribute_2:
        // Here i need an array
        json_array: [

                    ]
    }
    {
        some_json_object_atribute_1:
        some_json_object_atribute_2:
    }
]
```

But i'm only getting one row from json array. This is some part of the code:

```
$response["chat_rooms"] = array();

while ($chat_room = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $tmp = array();
        $tmp["chat_room_id"] = $chat_room["chat_room_id"];
        $unread_messages = $db->getAllUnreadMsgsFromChatRoom($user_id, $chat_room["chat_room_id"]);
        while ($unread_message = $unread_messages->fetch_assoc()) {
            // Here i need one json array
            $tmp["message_id"] = $unread_message["message_id"];
        }

        array_push($response["chat_rooms"], $tmp);
}
```

Comment: `$tmp["message_id"][]  = $unread_message["message_id"];` to dynamically add new items.

Answer (score -1):

You are overriding `$tmp["chat_room_id"]` in every run of the while loop.
The right syntax would be:

```
$tmp["chat_room_id"][] = $unread_message["message_id"];
```

or

```
array_push($tmp["chat_room_id"], $unread_message["message_id"]);
```